# Sharepoint list automatically created duplicate items

Tags: duplicate

I have a Sharepoint list that allows duplicate values in all columns as required by the business process but the entries are still considered as unique or individual records.

However, we have one user who added an item or two and it automatically created a duplicate item with exactly the same create date and time and all the information is the very much the same. It was like the item has copied itself. What must be causing this issue?

I am a novice Sharepoint user so the list I created is just a basic Sharepoint list, no programming done, no InfoPath forms, no workflows etc. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- Above mention issue may occur due slowness of application while user
  trying submit the form / tries submitting or clicking submit button
  multiple time(double click).

  - This can be overcome by making any column of the list form as unique.